# Proving a corollary of a statement about maps of finite sets

Tags: functions, solution-verification

I didn't have a problem proving that for any finite set $A$, an injection $f: A \to A$ is also a surjection. The more general statement is:

> If $A$ and $B$ are finite sets, possible distinct, with the same size, then any injection $f: A \to B$ is a surjective.

This statement is certainly true, but I'm trying to show that it's a corollary of the special case above for injections from $A$ to $A$. This is a connection I "hypothesized," so I am not 100% certain that there is a proof of the statement in this way, but here is my attempt.

> Let $f: A \to B$ be an injection between finite sets $A,B$ with $|A| = |B|$. Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $f$ is not surjective. So there exists $b \in B$ such that for all $a \in A$, $f(a) \neq b$. As $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality, there exists a bijection $g: B \to A$. The composition map
> $$
> g \circ f: A \to B \to A
> $$
> is a composition of injections and therefore injective. By the simpler statement, it is also surjective and hence bijective. Let $c = g(b)$. As $g$ is injective, this preimage of $c$ is unique. As $c \in A$ and $g \circ f$ is surjective, there exists $t \in A$ such that
> $$
> (g \circ f)(t) = c.
> $$
> That means that
> $$
> g(f(t)) = c. 
> $$
> As $g$ is injective and $g(b) = g(f(t)) = c$, $f(t) = b$. This contradicts the fact that $b$ was not in the image of $f$.

How does this look?

Comment: It is correct but could be shortened, reasoning directly instead of by contradiction: since $g\circ f$ is surjective and $g$ is bijective, $f$ is surjective.

Comment: @AnneBauval That seems much simpler, though I'm not fully sure why that I follow why this would imply that $f$ is surjective. My apologies if it's quite obvious and I'm missing it.